# How to avoid WKWebView auto-resizing it's contentSize

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I use WKWebView. The content size is adjusted with header meta like below:

```
<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no\">"
```

The content size is okay if it's height is within 10000 points. If its' height exceeds 10000 points, WKWebView seems to adjust it's content size.

Because I check it's contentSize property with KVO. After WKWebView's height exceeds 10000, next time the contentSize changed to box it's height within 10000. In this time, width widens...

Do you know how to reset WKWebKit auto resizing nature.

Comment: I found question's answer by myself. To add `shrink-to-fit=no` to viewport, webview doesn't shrink even if it shows long article! https://qox.jp/blog/ios9_viewport_workaround/